# Can't bind to 'placeholder' since it isn't a known property of 'ng-multiselect-dropdown'

Tags: angular, angular2-services, angular2-directives

I want to implement autocomplete feature , so an identical option i found was using multi-select drop-down. So i used this module -

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-multiselect-dropdown

But after ditto implementing, i get these errors -

Error -

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'placeholder' since it isn't a known property of 'ng- 
 multiselect-dropdown'.
1. If 'placeholder' is an Angular directive, then add 'CommonModule' 
 to the '@NgModule.imports' of this component.
2. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the 
'@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("

<ng-multiselect-dropdown
[ERROR ->][placeholder]="'custom placeholder'"
  [data]="dropdownList"
  [(ngModel)]="selectedItems"
"): ng:///AdminLayoutModule/HierarchySearchComponent.html@7:0
```

And when i comment placeholder in my component.html, i get this error -

```
Can't bind to 'data' since it isn't a known property of 'ng- 
multiselect-dropdown'.
1. If 'data' is an Angular directive, then add 'CommonModule' to the 
'@NgModule.imports' of this component.
2. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the 
 '@NgModule.schemas' of this component.
   "
<ng-multiselect-dropdown
[placeholder]="'custom placeholder'"
  [ERROR ->][data]="dropdownList"
  [(ngModel)]="selectedItems"
  [settings]="dropdownSettings"
"): ng:///AdminLayoutModule/HierarchySearchComponent.html@8:2
```

And the similar error continues till the last attribute.

**Update**

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';


import { AppRoutingModule } from './app.routing';
import { ComponentsModule } from './components/components.module';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { AdminLayoutComponent } from './layouts/admin-layout/admin-layout.component';

//-------------  Imported Modules -------------------------

import { NgMultiSelectDropDownModule } from 'ng-multiselect-dropdown';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';


@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    ComponentsModule,
    RouterModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    NgbModule.forRoot(),
    NgMultiSelectDropDownModule.forRoot(),
    CommonModule,


  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    AdminLayoutComponent,


  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Did you add proper module to `imports` in module config??

Comment: Yes , i included ==> import { NgMultiSelectDropDownModule } from 'ng-multiselect-dropdown'; in app.module.ts

Comment: but i mean module imports, not source file import.... You better paste app.module.ts

Comment: Please check the question

Comment: Try to import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser' as seen in your app.module.ts you haven't any instead you imported common module which are essential to use angular directives in feature modules and BrowserModule provides services that are essential to launch and run a browser app

Comment: does your  `component.html` has a `component.module.ts` ??

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**HierarchySearchComponent** - This is the component for which you are using `ng-multiselect-dropdown`.

So probably you would have **HierarchySearch.module.ts**.

You just remove **NgMultiSelectDropDownModule.forRoot()** from imports:[] in app.module.ts and import in **HierarchySearch.module.ts**.

It will work.!

Comment: could you please provide some  clear example. Whether do I need to create HierarchySearch.module.ts file in my project.?

Comment: Hi, what is the mean of HierarchySearchComponent, can you elaborate it I am also running with the same issue

Comment: Hi, you must remove NgMultiSelectDropDownModule.forRoot() from app.module.ts, then add: import { NgMultiSelectDropDownModule } from 'ng-multiselect-dropdown'; and NgMultiSelectDropDownModule.forRoot() inside .module.ts file where your current component is imported.

Answer (score 3):

Add the multi select import in ComponentsModule where you have all components are imported. It has worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

I faced this issue and solved by
Adding

```
import { NgMultiSelectDropDownModule } from 'ng-multiselect-dropdown';
```

and

```
@NgModule({
imports: [
    NgMultiSelectDropDownModule
]
})
```

to **xxxx.module.ts** file where your component is imported not to **app.module.ts** file

Answer (score 1):

check whether you are imported you are imported NgMultiSelectDropDownModule to module.ts

```
import { NgMultiSelectDropDownModule } from 'ng-multiselect-dropdown';

@NgModule({


imports: [
    NgMultiSelectDropDownModule
  ],
```

Answer (score 1):

I am also working with angular 7 But my issue is resolved. I just import `NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA` and include in same module where `ng-multiselect-dropdown` module included `@NgModule`:

```
import { NgModule ,NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA} from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';


@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    AngularMultiSelectModule,
  ],
  schemas:[NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA], 
})
export class SettingsModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

**If** you get this error in your **unit test**, you need to add the module to your `imports` in the `TestBed.configureTestingModule`

```
await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [YourComponent, ...MockComponents(...)],
      imports: [
        NgMultiSelectDropDownModule
      ],
      providers: [...
...
```

Answer (score -1):

Normally, this error occurs when you missed some imports. Please add these line if missing:

`import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';`