# Use ng-multiselect-dropdown in a component instead of app.module.ts

Tags: node.js, angular, asp.net-core

I am trying to use the [ng-multiselect-dropdown](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-multiselect-dropdown) component in another component/page (viz. registered through RouterModule.forRoot in app.mudule.ts).
I have imported it in my component as suggested in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52925489/cant-bind-to-placeholder-since-it-isnt-a-known-property-of-ng-multiselect-d)-

```
import { Component, OnInit, NgModule, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from 
'@angular/core';
import { NgMultiSelectDropDownModule } from 'ng-multiselect-dropdown';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
@Component({
selector: "ng-multiselect-dropdown",
templateUrl: "./multiselect.component.html"
})

@NgModule({   
 imports: [
 NgMultiSelectDropDownModule.forRoot(),
 FormsModule
 ],
 schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
})


export class MultiSelectComponent implements OnInit {
//constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
//  private router: Router,
//  private http: HttpClient,
//  @Inject('BASE_URL') private baseUrl: string) {}
dropdownList = [];
selectedItems = [];
dropdownSettings = {};
ngOnInit() {
  this.dropdownList = [
    { item_id: 1, item_text: 'Mumbai' },
    { item_id: 2, item_text: 'Bangaluru' },
    { item_id: 3, item_text: 'Pune' },
    { item_id: 4, item_text: 'Navsari' },
    { item_id: 5, item_text: 'New Delhi' }
  ];
  this.selectedItems = [
    { item_id: 3, item_text: 'Pune' },
    { item_id: 4, item_text: 'Navsari' }
  ];
  this.dropdownSettings = {
    singleSelection: false,
    idField: 'item_id',
    textField: 'item_text',
    selectAllText: 'Select All',
    unSelectAllText: 'UnSelect All',
    itemsShowLimit: 3,
    allowSearchFilter: true
  };
}
onItemSelect(item: any) {
  console.log(item);
}
onSelectAll(items: any) {
  console.log(items);
}
}
```

But I get the following errors, when I look in the browser developer tools.
emplate parse errors:
Can't bind to 'placeholder' since it isn't a known property of 'ng-multiselect-dropdown'.
1. If 'placeholder' is an Angular directive, then add 'CommonModule' to the '@NgModule.imports' of this component.
2. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component.
Can't bind to 'data' since it isn't a known property of 'ng-multiselect-dropdown'.
Can't bind to 'settings' since it isn't a known property of 'ng-multiselect-dropdown'.

The html of the page is as below -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8" />
   <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <ng-multiselect-dropdown [placeholder]="'custom placeholder'"
                       [data]="dropdownList"
                       [(ngModel)]="selectedItems"
                       [settings]="dropdownSettings"
                       (onSelect)="onItemSelect($event)"
                       (onSelectAll)="onSelectAll($event)">
  </ng-multiselect-dropdown>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think that you can find your answer here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52925489/cant-bind-to-placeholder-since-it-isnt-a-known-property-of-ng-multiselect-d)

Comment: I have tried the above link, which is where I am getting an error

Comment: It looks wrong that you have defined your own selector as "ng-multiselect-dropdown", making it 'override' the imported one.

Try renaming it to e.g. 

`@Component({
selector: "my-dropdown",
templateUrl: "./multiselect.component.html"
})`

Comment: So, should I just remove the line - selector: "ng-multiselect-dropdown" ?

Comment: Whar happens if you just rename it? It looks like you are trying to build your own angular component so you would most likely need a selector (with your own defined name)

Comment: Tried both removing and renaming the selector, but the error remains the same. Am I importing it correctly?

Comment: Maybe a stupid question, but did you add it properly ? you know  - npm install ...

Comment: Yes, I did add them..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it to work. The **NgMultiSelectDropDownModule** module itself should be imorted to app.module.ts. The **ngOnInit()** method should be used inside the component.ts. As correctly pointed out by others, the component's own selector should be different from the **ng-multiselect-dropdown** selector used in the component html.

Answer (score 1):

This error means that the component's module doesn't have the required imports.
Try importing the module in this components' module file.

Comment: Just to make sure this isn't an issue with incorrect importing, remove the `[placeholder]="'custom placeholder'"` and check whether the default value Select is displayed.

Comment: It's not just placeholder, it shows the same error for other properties like data, settings etc. Should be something wrong with the importing i think.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
[placeholder]="'custom placeholder'"
```

use

```
[value]="custom placeholder"
```

And of course check that the import in the module It's done the correct way

However I checked the official documentation and you can bind the placeholder property

Comment: Now it shows "Can't bind to 'value' since it isn't a known property of 'ng-multiselect-dropdown'

Comment: This is wrong, if you skip the ' then angular will try to evaluate the "custom placeholder" as en expression, expecting the MultiSelectComponent  class to have a property with that name.
Furthermore, the ng-multiselect-dropdown dont have a property named "value"

Comment: Yes right, I were just trying on my mac, multiselector in general doesn't have value and placeholder